# Code Golf: Numeric Ranges

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf

### Challenge

Compactify a long list of numbers by replacing consecutive runs with ranges.

### Example

#### Input

`1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15`
The input is guaranteed to be in ascending order and will not contain duplicates.

#### Output

`1 - 4, 7, 8, 10, 12 - 15`
Note that ranges of two numbers should be left as is.  (`7, 8`; not `7 - 8`)

### Rules

You can accept a sorted list of integers (or equivalent datatype) as a method parameter, from the commandline, or from standard in.  (pick whichever option results in shorter code)
You can output a list of strings by printing them, or by returning either a single string or set of strings.

### Reference Implementation

(C#)

```cs
IEnumerable<string> Sample(IList<int> input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; ) {
        var start = input[i];
        int size = 1;
        while (++i < input.Count && input[i] == start + size)
            size++;

        if (size == 1)
            yield return start.ToString();
        else if (size == 2) {
            yield return start.ToString();
            yield return (start + 1).ToString();
        } else if (size > 2)
            yield return start + " - " + (start + size - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: CW for questions was [removed a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action). I also believe that programmers is supposed to be where code golf should go (at least according to the FAQ and Jeffs' post about it).

Comment: @Oded: I know.  I don't see any code golf questions on Programmers, whereas I do see some (new ones) here.  The right place to put it is [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles), but I can't.

Comment: @SLaks - I kinda noticed that myself...

Comment: @SLaks: Looks like you're assuming input is sorted, is that correct?

Comment: Yes; I forgot to mention that.  Fixed.

Comment: @Oded, @SLaks, this is the appropriate place for code golf as of now.

Comment: @SLaks: Forgot to ask as well: it's distinct? (i.e., no `1, 1, 2, 5, 6` or whatever)

Comment: CW requests should be done by flags, not by hints above in the question. I've done it for you.

Comment: Like these Code Golf and other puzzles? Commit to the [Code Golf & Programming Puzzles area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles?referrer=oAEDY7RBfMtqY44vShJFww2).

Comment: @gnibbler: If you really want to, I suppose.   It would count against you.

Comment: Duplicate problem, and a spoiler - has been published already in http://codegolf.com/home-on-the-range . Please do not post solutions here, so that solutions won't be used to inflate rankings on codegolf.com

Comment: @Nas: It's not quite the same; they want `5, 6` to map to `5-6`, and I don't.  Since that requirement adds some complexity, I don't think there's anything to be afraid of.

Comment: Code golf now belongs on code golf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python, 83 characters

```
def f(l,a=2):
 for x in l:
  b,a=a,(x+1in l)*(x-1in l)
  if a<1:print',- '[b],`x`,
```

Demo:

```
>>> l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> f(l)
  1 - 4 , 7 , 8 , 10 , 12 - 15
```

Comment: copy and pasting your first snippet acutally it's more than 83 chars

Comment: @yes: You're counting line breaks as two characters.

Comment: Very nice, but why the backticks around x?

Comment: @TomaszGandor: honestly, I'm not sure (and this is pretty old!). Seems to work fine without backticks, yes...

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 98 characters

```
def f(a):
 for x in a:
  if x-1not in a or x+1not in a:print x,"-"if x+1in a and x+2in a else",",
```

### Python - 86 characters

This one doesn't include an extra ',' at the end

```
f=lambda a:''.join(`x`+",-"[(x+1in a)&x+2in a]for x in a if(x-1in a)&(x+1in a)^1)[:-1]
```

Comment: `if x-1not in a or x+1not in a:print x,",-"[x+1in a and x+2in a],` is shorter

Comment: I don't know python very well, but doesn't this print one extra "," in the end?

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 165 characters

```
a=[]
def o(a)print "#{@s}#{a[0]}#{"#{a.size<3?',':' -'} #{a[-1]}"if a.size>1}";@s=', 'end
ARGV[0].split(', ').each{|n|if a[0]&&a[-1].succ!=n;o(a);a=[]end;a<<n;};o(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 166 characters

```
#define o std::cout
void f(std::vector<int> v){for(int i=0,b=0,z=v.size();i<z;)i==z-1||v[i+1]>v[i]+1?b?o<<", ":o,(i-b?o<<v[b]<<(i-b>1?" - ":", "):o)<<v[i],b=++i:++i;}
```

Don't you all just love abusing the `?:` operator? ;)

More readable version:

```
#define o std::cout
void f(std::vector<int> v){
    for(int i=0,b=0,z=v.size();i<z;)
        i==z-1||v[i+1]>v[i]+1 ?
            b?o<<", ":o,
            (i-b?o<<v[b]<<(i-b>1?" - ":", "):o)<<v[i],
            b=++i
        :++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 442/206 chars

```
(defun d (l)
  (if l
      (let ((f (car l))
        (r (d (cdr l))))
      (if r
          (if (= (+ f 1) (caar r))
          (push `(,f ,(cadar r)) (cdr r))
          (push `(,f ,f) r))
          `((,f ,f))
          ))
      nil))

(defun p (l)
  (mapc #'(lambda (x)
          (if (= (car x) (cadr x))
          (format t "~a " (car x))
          (if (= (+ 1 (car x)) (cadr x))
              (format t "~a ~a " (car x) (cadr x))
              (format t "~a-~a " (car x) (cadr x)))))
      (d l)))
```

The "d" function rewrites the input list into a canonical form.  For fun I did this entirely recursively.  The "p" function formats the output to the equivalent of the reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 188 chars

```
let r(x::s)=
 let f=printf
 let p x=function|1->f"%A "x|2->f"%A %A "x (x+1)|n->f"%A-%A "x (x+n-1)
 let rec l x n=function|y::s when y=x+n->l x (n+1)s|y::s->p x n;l y 1 s|[]->p x n
 l x 1 s
```

More readable:

```
let range (x::xs) =
  let f = printf
  let print x = function
    | 1 -> f "%A " x
    | 2 -> f "%A %A " x (x+1)
    | n -> f "%A-%A " x (x+n-1)
  let rec loop x n = function
    | y::ys when y=x+n ->
        loop x (n+1) ys
    | y::ys ->
        print x n
        loop y 1 ys
    | [] ->
        print x n
  loop x 1 xs
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby : 123 characters

```
def y(n) t=[];r=[];n.each_with_index do |x,i| t<<x;if(x.succ!=n[i+1]);r=((t.size>2)?r<<t[0]<<-t[-1]:r+t);t=[];end;end;r;end
```

More Readable

```
def y(n) 
t=[];r=[];
n.each_with_index do |x,i|
 t << x
 if (x.succ != n[i+1])
    r = ((t.size > 2) ? r << t[0] << -t[-1] : r+t)  
    t=[]
 end
 end
 r
end
```

And execute like

```
 > n=[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
 > y n
 => [1, -4, 7, 8, 10, 12, -15]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 95 chars

(actually it's the **second language** after python)

Given `$a=array(numbers);`

Algos:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){$c=$i;while($a[$i+2]==$a[$i]+2)$i++;echo $a[$c],$i-$c>1?'-':',';}
```

Comment: actually this throws notices about undefined offsets... but hey, the rules don't say stderr must be clean... but the output format is not quite right. edit: also it doesn't account for where the input comes from so your 95 chars aren't valid imho

Comment: @luxifer: i don't quite remeber of this problem, i will try my script again and i will update