# Convert numeric sequences to ranges

Tags: c#

I have the following string in C#:

```
string a="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,22,45,66,88,100,101,102,103,104,105,140,199";
```

I would like to generate the following output:

1-10,22,45,66,88,100-105,140,199 grouping the consecutive numbers into ranges on this way

"initialnumber-endnumber" and leaving the others as it is.

Could you give me a hand on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we'd be happy to help you through anywhere you are stuck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659511/code-golf-numeric-ranges

Comment: @SLaks: that seems to be a `Python`. Considering OP's answer it doesn't seem to be suitable for *this* question.

Comment: @cadrell0 - that usually isn't required here. Watch the list below.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's not required, but it should be, and asking the OP is still perfectly acceptable.  That there are lots of people willing to do all of someone's work for them is unfortunate, not desirable.

Comment: @Servy is this a Q and A site, wait I think this is a discussion for the meta site?

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, this is a QA site, not a "do all of my work for me so that I don't have to" site.  There is a difference.

Comment: I just thought this was a simple question. I wonder if the OP finds the answers unfortunate and undesirable? I guess its important that they OP reviews the answers and all readers may learn somthing from them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> Rangify(IList<int> input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; ) {
        var start = input[i];
        int size = 1;
        while (++i < input.Count && input[i] == start + size)
            size++;

        if (size == 1)
            yield return start.ToString();
        else if (size == 2) {
            yield return start.ToString();
            yield return (start + 1).ToString();
        } else if (size > 2)
            yield return start + " - " + (start + size - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this to combine lists of objects into ranges also. It works well. Thanks!

Comment: This could be generalized to IEnumerable<int> as only the current element of input (`input[i]`) is accessed and the current position in the input (`i`) only moves forward. That would cost some performance, though, as an enumerator would need to be allocated and its MoveNext is likely more expensive than `++i`. Still, this is nice to know in case an actual sequence/stream needs to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

okay, first step, enumerate string as ordered integers.

```
var numbers = a.Split(',').Select(int.Parse()).OrderBy(i => i);
```

So, then we could use these two functions to enumerate the ranges like this.

```
private static string RangeToString(int first, int last)
{
    if ( last != first )
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", first, last);
    }
    else
    {
        return last.ToString();
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetRanges(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    var last = numbers.First();
    var first = last;
    foreach(var number in numbers.Skip(1))
    {
        if (lastNumber + 1 != number)
        {
            yield return RangeToString(first, last);
            first = number;
        }

        last == number;
    }

    yield return RangeToString(first, last);
}
```

Then we can put it together like this,

```
public static string GetRangedList(string list)
{
    var numbers = list.Split(',').Select(int.Parse()).OrderBy(i => i);
    return string.Join(",", GetRanges(numbers));
}
```

Which obviously you would call like this

```
var b = GetRangedList(a);
```